# AngularJS dropdownlist with search and treeview functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a requirement to create a control or directive below (please see image). The directive has a dropdownlist, when you click the dropdownlist it will show the the searchbox and the treeview. When you click the item in the treeview, the value should be display in the dropdownlist. When you enter a value in the textbox, the data should filter the treeview with the match value, if the data match under the hierarchy it will show the hierarchy. For example if you search for Option 1.1.1, the result should be Option 1 > Option 1.1 > Option 1.1.1.

Here is the current implementation I am working on which is not working so far which I copied from github https://plnkr.co/edit/gmv0aUiBUMnOlvxzFdRt?p=preview

Other solution like kendo using angularjs which has the same functionality that I am looking for is acceptable.

demo.controller.js

```
/**
 * Created by Shripad on 2015-Nov-17.
 */

angular.module('App',['tree.dropdown']).controller('treeDropdownCtrl', treeDropdownCtrl);

function treeDropdownCtrl() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.treeData = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Option 1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Option 1.1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "Option 1.1.1",
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Option 1.1.2",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Option 2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Option 2.1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "Option 2.1.1",
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "name": "Option 2.1.2",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

    // Set default selected...
    ctrl.selected = ctrl.treeData[0];


    ctrl.update = function (){
        ctrl.treeData = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Level 1",
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Level 2",
            }
        ]
        ctrl.selected = ctrl.treeData[0];
    }
}
```

tree-dropdown.js

```
/**
 * Created by Shripad on 2015-Nov-17.
 */

angular.module('tree.dropdown', []).directive('treeDropdown', treeDropdown);

treeDropdown.$inject = ['$compile'];

function treeDropdown($compile){
    var template = "<div class='select' ng-click='openTree()'><p>{{selected.name}}</p></div>";
    template += "<div class='list' ng-show='isOpen'></div>";

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            selected: '='
        },

        template: template,
        controller: function($scope, $element){
            ctrl = $scope;
            ctrl.isOpen = false;

            ctrl.openTree = function(){
                ctrl.isOpen = ctrl.isOpen? false:true;
            }

            ctrl.childClick = function(obj){
                setSelected(ctrl, obj);
                ctrl.isOpen = false;
                ctrl.$apply();
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var list =  angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.list'));

            scope.$watchGroup(['data', 'selected'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
                list.html('');
                list.append("<li><input type='text' placeholder='Query' ng-model='query'/></li>");
                if(!scope.selected){
                    setSelected (scope, null);
                }
                var options = getOptions(scope, scope.data, 0);
                list.append($compile(options)(scope));
            });

            // Close on click outside the dropdown...            
            angular.element(document).bind('click', function(event){
                if (element !== event.target && !element[0].contains(event.target)) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.isOpen = false;
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    };

    function getOptions(scope, data, level){

        var optionUL = angular.element("<ul></ul>");


        angular.forEach(data, function(obj){
            var optionLI = angular.element("<li></li>");
            var optionA = angular.element("<p ng-class='{selected:selected.id=="+obj.id+"}' class='level-"+level+"'>"+obj.name+"</p>");
            optionLI.append(optionA);

            // Set selected option if selected id or object exist..
            if(scope.selected==obj){
                setSelected (scope, obj);
            }

            optionA.bind("click", function(){
                scope.childClick(obj);
            })

            if(obj.children){
                optionLI.append(getOptions(scope, obj.children, level+1));
            }
            optionUL.append(optionLI);
        })

        return optionUL;
    }

    function setSelected(scope, obj){
        if(obj){
            scope.selected = obj;
        } else {
            scope.selected = null;
        }
    }
}
```

tree-dropdown.css

```
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.tree-dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   font-size: 13px;
   width: 300px;
}

.tree-dropdown .select {
   padding: 0 10px;
   height: 32px;
   display: block;
   line-height: 14px;
   color: #333333;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
   -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
   transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.tree-dropdown .select::after {
   content: " ";
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 4px solid transparent;
   border-right: 4px solid transparent;
   border-top: 5px solid #CDCDCD;
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   top: 13px;
}

.tree-dropdown p {
   line-height: 32px;
   margin: 0;
}

.tree-dropdown .list{
   box-sizing: content-box;
   position: absolute;
   top: 33px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: #cccccc;
   border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
   z-index: 1100;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   max-height: 300px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
   box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}

.tree-dropdown ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}

.tree-dropdown ul:first-child { 
   padding: 0px;
}

.tree-dropdown .list p:hover{
   background: #eee;
}

.tree-dropdown .list p.selected{
   background: #DDDBFF;
}

.tree-dropdown .level-0 {
   padding-left: 15px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-1 {
   padding-left: 30px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-2 {
   padding-left: 45px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-3 {
   padding-left: 60px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-4 {
   padding-left: 75px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-5 {
   padding-left: 90px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-6 {
   padding-left: 105px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-7 {
   padding-left: 120px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-8 {
   padding-left: 135px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-9 {
   padding-left: 150px
}
.tree-dropdown .level-10 {
   padding-left: 110px
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Demo angular-tree-dropdown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tree-dropdown.css" />
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="tree-dropdown.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .col-xs-6 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
    }
    label {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Demo angular-tree-dropdown</h2>
    <div class="row" ng-controller="treeDropdownCtrl as ctrl">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <tree-dropdown class="tree-dropdown" data="ctrl.treeData" selected="ctrl.selected"></tree-dropdown>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button ng-click="ctrl.update()">Update Data Array</button>
        <button ng-click="ctrl.selected=ctrl.treeData[1]">Select by Object</button>
        <label>Selected Id: {{ctrl.selected.id}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of Kendo UI (R2 2018) there is a new widget called DropDownTree that seems to be exactly what you are looking for. [Here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdowntree/index) is the demo page.